# Get a url to a git commit from the command line

Tags: git, github, hyperlink

I like to share links to git commits with other people. It's useful to be able to get these without too much clicking in emacs, there is a package in emacs that I use (https://github.com/sshaw/git-link) but I want to do this from the command line.

Is there an easy way to get a link to a commit from from the command line? (I use `github`)

## Related

`git rev-parse HEAD` gives you the commit from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This linux command should work for GitHub if your remote is called 'origin' and you use https to access your origin

```
echo "$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/\.git$//g')/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL you'd need for, say, a Bitbucket-hosted Git repository is *different* from the URL you'd need for a GitHub-hosted Git repository.  Git itself doesn't have such links: each hosting system in use has to invent its own.

Since you want a *GitHub-specific* link, you can generate one, knowing that it will begin with `https://github.com/` or `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/`.  After that comes the name of the repository, e.g., `git/git/`.  If you then want a particular file, the next part is `blob/`, then either a branch name or a commit hash ID, then the path to the file.  The same scheme works to obtain raw file content when suing `raw.githubusercontent.com`.

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of Git have a `git remote get-url` subcommand which is nicer than `git config --get`, particularly because it resolves [`insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).

Here is a simple script which uses `get-url` to get the base URL for the current repo (in easy copy and paste form).

```perl
cat <<'EOF' > ~/bin/git-link
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;

my $remote = (qx(git status -sb) =~ /\.\.\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/)[0] || "origin";
my $remote_uri = qx{git remote get-url "$remote"};

chomp $remote_uri;
# Logic carefully arranged to work for github, sourcehut (sr.ht) and gitlab.
$remote_uri =~ s/^git\@//;
$remote_uri =~ s/\.git$//;
$remote_uri =~ s!^([.\w]+):!https://$1/! unless $remote_uri =~ /^http/;

say $remote_uri;
EOF
chmod +x ~/bin/git-link
```

This can then be used via something like:

```
echo $(git link)/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Which you could configure as a git alias, with something like:

```bash
$ git config --global alias.clink '!echo $(git link)/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)'
$ git clink
https://some-repo/commit/abcde
```

You may be interested in a tool I wrote to make `git log` contain links: https://gist.github.com/dgl/ef848e75c03c09b0db63a43173ee5662/

Your terminal will need to support embedded hyperlinks, but provided it does you can use this combined with `git log -1` and simply copy the link from the commit ID.